# Renaming google play console tracks

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I inherited two apps, which are whitelabels of the same app.

First app:
open-testing track is named "open-testing" and i can rename it to whatever i want, but the already existing names of other tracks. closed-testing track is named "beta". I cannot rename the closed testing track.

Second app:
open-testing track is named "beta" and i cannot rename it, as the button for renaming it is not displayed. closed-testing tracks are named "alpha" and "open-testing". I cannot rename the closed testing tracks.

I want to have the open testing track have the same name for both apps, so I can easily have automated deployments for both apps. How can I achieve this? How was it at the first place possible for anyone to rename the open testing "beta" track. I do not see this option for any of my apps.